# RegEx to select one or two lines

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I have the following text

```
828 :     test_case := 9001;
829 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> <= force (others => '1');
830 :     wait_fall_edges(1);
831 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> 
832 : <= force (others => '0');
833 :     wait_fall_edges(1);
834 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> <= release;
835 : 
836 :     test_case := 9004;
837 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= force '1';
838 :     wait_fall_edges(1);
839 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= force '0';
840 :     wait_fall_edges(1);
841 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= release;
```

I'm trying with python to get (in the above text) the lines where a signal is forced (**<= force**). 
However I do not seem to be able to achieve this. I can either get 829, 832, 837, and 839 but not (831 and 832).

I have **r"^.*<=\s*force.*?$"gmi** which works if the "force" is a one liner.

**EDIT**

My desired output from above is to get the following list

```
829 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> <= force (others => '1');
831 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> 
832 : <= force (others => '0');
837 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= force '1';
839 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= force '0';
```

Regards

Comment: Whats the desired output?

Comment: Not clear why line `831` is in the output?

Comment: line 831 and line 832 are one line. the command have just been split over two lines.

Comment: its a use case I've forced the output this way to test our system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
mystring = '''
828 :     test_case := 9001;
829 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> <= force (others => '1');
830 :     wait_fall_edges(1);
831 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> 
832 : <= force (others => '0');
833 :     wait_fall_edges(1);
834 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> <= release;
835 : 
836 :     test_case := 9004;
837 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= force '1';
838 :     wait_fall_edges(1);
839 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= force '0';
840 :     wait_fall_edges(1);
841 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= release;
'''

output = re.findall(r'^\d+.*(?:\n[^:]+: +)?<= force.*$',mystring,re.MULTILINE)
for line in output:
    print (line)
```

Prints:

```
829 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> <= force (others => '1');
831 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.data_to_ext_device : t_adc_spi_data >> 
832 : <= force (others => '0');
837 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= force '1';
839 :     <<signal .ads8363_adc_cnt_tb.u_ads8363_adc_cnt.adc_mode_o : std_logic >> <= force '0';
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/DVVqKG/1).